# Email to WorkItem - EWS 2007_SP1 & TFS 2010

Tags: c#, tfs, exchangewebservices

I am trying to setup an EWS to TFS support ticket system. I am following this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh335060.aspx

He utilizes Exchange 2010, whereas we are running Exchange 2007_SP1 through Microsoft MyCompany Portal.

Internally we are running TFS 2010.

I've deployed the code to a local IIS install with my local domain credentials in the Application Pool.
I've setup the credentials in the Application Settings for the Exchange EWS and TFS server.
I've successfully subscribed to EWS and have the confirmation of subscription.

The frustration is once this has been setup and I send an email to my Exchange email (the email address I am temporarily using to test this), TFS never picks it up and does not create a WorkItem.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might sound silly, but I spent forever debugging a notification issue, and it all got tracked down to not having the right firewall ports open on the server receiving the notification.  Have you checked that the firewall is allowing whatever port the webservice is listening for notifications on?

Also, have you tried debugging the webservice directly and making sure it is receiving the notifications?  I know you said the subscription is confirmed, but wasn't sure if you'd validated that the notifications were actually being received.

Comment: I checked ... and it was simply that our EWS sits outside of our network where TFS sits. Simple ... but I kept overlooking it.